# Qual è il significato di "volgere" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Rinascimento privato* di Maria Bellonci ho letto:

> Mi interrogo ancora una volta: perché non ho rispostovné di persona, né dettando a Pirro Donati: potevo comporre lettere fredde, modelli di superiore amicizia, anche severe per molte riprensioni. Quale epistolario potrebbe essere questo, di un tono mai sentito; e **volgerebbe** sui misteri concreti degli uomini.

Ho cercato il verbo "volgere" in parecchi dizionari, tuttavia non riesco a capire il suo significato in questo passaggio. Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uno dei significati di "volgere" è "andare verso". Nel brano, dunque, si intende che un epistolario come quello descritto "andrebbe verso", vale a dire "si occuperebbe dei" «misteri concreti degli uomini».